std::vector: why out_of_range error doesn't happen?
Mac M1.
I learn C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup's book. He show the similar example in his "Programming. Principles and Practice Using C++" book (chapter 5.6.2). Also he writes this exception (out_of_range) is to be occurred.
clang++ --version
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin24.0.0
Thread model: posix

My code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    try{
        std::vector<int> items;

        constexpr int size = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            items.push_back(i * 10);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= items.size(); ++i){ // out of range!
            std::cout << i << " -> " << items[i] << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range){
        std::cerr << "Range error!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...){
        std::cerr << "Something wrong..." << std::endl;
    }
}

Compilation command:
clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp

Result:
./a.out 
0 -> 0
1 -> 10
2 -> 20
3 -> 30
4 -> 40
5 -> 0
Success!

I've expected to get the out of range exception but it wasn't happened. Why?

@AhmedAEK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/out-of-range-class?view=msvc-170

If you read the out_of_range docs it is thrown by the .at member functions, not the brackets operators, those are not checked, in general you shouldn't expect c++ to put unnecessary checks on the hot paths

@AhmedAEK Bjarne Stroustrup show such example in his "Programming. Principles and Practice Using C++" book He writes this exception is to be occurred.

Can you link that chapter ? Which page or chapter, etc ....

@AhmedAEK chapter 5.6.2. (Russian edition).

@AndreyBushman If it says what you say it does then it is simply wrong. vector::at throws std::out_of_range not vector::operator[].

Use vector's .at() method

You are right the book does say that, it is likely a mistake as bjarne didn't create vector (he didn't even create the STL library which the modern standard library is based on), in any case there are proposals to have C++ do bound checks in the future, but it won't throw an exception and only "error out" in debug mode ..... which a lot of implementations already do anyway.

I believe you are confusing Bjarne Stroustrup's vector and std::vector.
Stroustrup's PPPheaders.h uses a #define vector Checked_vector. A Checked_vector changes the behaviour of operator[] to use at instead in PPP_support.h.
As has already been stated in comments and the other answer, the std::vector does not do bounds checking for operator[]

You are right. I don't use this header file because it throws compilation time errors in clang++ on my Mac M1. Also I read the second edition of the book.

Debug mode might actually define index operator to call at or there might be an assert. But it's left to implementor. In release mode however, it is almost impossible that a sane implementor wasted clock cycles on bounds check.

std::vector's operator[] doesn't perform any validity check on the index. If it is out-of-bounds, then that's a violation of operator[]'s preconditions and therefore undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. Throwing an exception is permissible (in in debug builds the compiler might to that), but producing non-sense or crashing are just as valid.
std::vector also has the .at member function which doesn't have the precondition that the index is in-bounds and instead throws a std::out_of_bounds exception if the index is not in-bounds. It seems that you wanted to use that:
    for(int i = 0; i <= items.size(); ++i){ // out of range
        std::cout << i << " -> " << items.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

However, in general .at is not used often. Accessing the vector out-of-bounds is usually an indicator for a program logic flaw that shouldn't happen at all and not just an exceptional execution flow that is intended to happen. Exceptions are not usually a solution to a programming error.

I learn C++ from a book and just check the code written by the author and expect the behavior he describes in the text. So I was surprised that the exception did not happen, although the creator of C++ writes the opposite in his book.
